# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Permissions Issue?

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, mysql

Can't start clickhouse-server today after MySQL 5.7 update. Errors I get from `sudo journalctl -u clickhouse-server` are...

Couldn't save preprocessed config to /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/config.xml: Access to file denied: /var/lib/clickho
Logging trace to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log
Logging errors to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log
systemd[1]: clickhouse-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=70/n/a
systemd[1]: clickhouse-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log says

{} Application: DB::ErrnoException: Cannot open file /var/lib/clickhouse/status, errno: 13, strerror: Permission denied

The /var/lib/clickhouse dir is symlink to /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse user clickhouse group clickhouse owns the folders. It says it is permission problem, while it is not. Trued chowning just in case with

```
chown -R clickhouse:clickhouse /var/lib/clickhouse
chown -R clickhouse:clickhouse /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse
```

Issue persists.

Any ideas? ClickHouse server still claims it is a permission issue, but it is not. ClickHouse 21.1.2.15 with revision 54445.

**Something is pretending to be permissions issue. I can't even copy the files to another server because of permissions issue.**

```
ll -d /var/lib
```

drwxr-xr-x 50 root root 4096 Jan 16 09:51 /var/lib/

```
ll -d /var/lib/clickhouse
```

lrwxrwxrwx 1 clickhouse clickhouse 25 Apr 11 2020 /var/lib/clickhouse -> /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse/

```
ll -d /var/lib/mysql
```

drwx------ 12 mysql mysql 4096 Feb 2 08:25 /var/lib/mysql/

```
ll -d /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse
```

drwxr-xr-x 14 clickhouse clickhouse 4096 Jan 20 18:47 /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse/

Any ideas, please? What does MySQL update screw up this time? : )

Comment: The permissions of `/var/lib/mysql/clickhouse` are `clickhouse:clickhouse`? *That's* your problem. MySQL database files *must* be owned by `mysql:mysql` and have `640` permissions. This is 100% a permissions issue ⇢ the wrong permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And how is that the problem? The service clickhouse-server is run by user clickhouse, while the service mysql is run by user mysql.
Clickhouse files are in /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse and everything else in /var/lib/mysql is owned by mysql user/group. What are you suggesting? To run clickhouse-server with user mysql?

Comment: I don't know what "clickhouse-server" is, but `/var/lib/mysql/clickhouse` tells me there is a MySQL database with the name `clickhouse` that is expected to run. If clickhouse has its own built-in MySQL engine, then it has picked a really poor location to store its files, as MySQL will scream any time foreign files and directories are put into its storage location. MySQL database files can only be read by MySQL. Period. Clickhouse may *connect* to MySQL to access the data, but it cannot own the files that MySQL uses.

Comment: ClickHouse Server is a database server for big data. I picked the location because of partitioning

/ - 10GB
/var/log - 50GB
/var/www - 50GB
/var/lib/mysql - the rest of disk space.

So as you see, I had to symlink /var/lib/clickhouse to /var/lib/mysql/clickhouse and move the data there.

Was not an issue till I tried to update MySQL today.

Comment: Can try to change the mount point of /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib and then move clickhouse data back to /var/lib/clickhouse. Symlink most probably causing this issue. Not to mention mysql update failed because of some table missing. Hm...

Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' doesn't exist
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5